# Create an array using a pointer

Tags: c++

Basically I want to create a multidimensional array using a size variable passed to my class but am not sure how to do it.

I've tried doing

```
//Class header
Tile * gameTile;

//Class cpp
gameTile = new Tile[size][size];
```

It doesnt mind `new Tile[size]` but not `[size][size]`. Why is this?

Comment: Expression must have a constant value. Ive changed the prototype and that to const but nothing :/

Comment: One of the dimension must be constant, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Answer (score 4):

That fails because only the first dimension of an allocated array may have a dynamic size. To overcome this limitation you can use a 2-dimensional vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile> > gameTile(size, std::vector<Tile>(size));
```

Comment: How would I declare that in a class header? How would I change the size of it depending on the parameter passed to the init function?

Comment: @Split Well vector has a [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) member function, so you can use that.

Comment: As for the class header - where are you intending to use this? Inside main, for a class?

Comment: Am intending to use this in a class

Answer (score 1):

Like in the link of Vlad mentions, you could use vectors, or for something more quick you could use the following code to initialize the bidimentional array:

```
int i;
int ** intTile;
intTile = new  int*[5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    intTile[i] = new int[5];
}
```

Comment: It's not really any quicker to code than a vector of vectors and not really quicker to run than a specialized matrix class. It fails at memory management much more than both, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
Tile *gameTile = &((new Tile[size][size])[0][0]);
```

this store the address for the first element in your multy dimensional array to gameTile.

Comment: `new Tile[size][size]` is not valid C++

Comment: @kotlomoy it works fine for me, are you saying you cant initialize an array using 'size'?

Comment: You can, only if `size` is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Although you want to use two dimensional arrays, I just want to point out for completeness that you can also use a one dimensional array for your purpose. If it is of dimension size by size you have:

```
gameTile = new Tile[size*size];
//now gameTile[y][x] becomes:
Tile t = gameTile[x + y*size];

//if array is not square
gameTile = new Tile[width*height];
//now gameTile[y][x] becomes:
Tile t = gameTile[x + y*width];
```